# Get row index of the nth valid numeric value in a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet with the column A2:A7 filled as:
A2=A4=A5=< blank>; A3=3; A6=a; A7=4;

How to get the row index of the second numeric value of the column A? In this case "6" (6th row from my data set that start in A2 and refers to A7).

In the same example, if I fill A2=0, the formula should return "2".

I need to use just Excel formulas, I can't use VBAs of macro codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
{=SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER($A$2:$A$7)*ROW($A$2:$A$7)=0,"",ROW($A$2:$A$7)),2)-1}
```

The 2 close to the end will determine if you interested in the `nth` smallest numeric value. In this case the `2nd`.

Note that it's an array formula entered through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Looking into your answer. But I new to return the row index, not the number itself and the numbers order can make influence in the answer (it have to return the `nth` number and not the `nth` smallest number).

Comment: It does exactly what you want! Don't get fooled by the looks of small, that s just to get nth number. Since the function first returns all rows with a numeric value it is automatically the smallest on the first hit, etc.

Comment: For a better understanding you can step through the formula with evaluate and check the process ;)